# General trick to factorize an inequality of the kind $a+b\leq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, polynomials, power-series, factoring

I have found this method in solving this kind of inequality :

> > Let $x,y>0$ such that $x+y=1$ then we have :
> > $$x^{2y}+y^{2x}\leq 1$$

Well now we want to solve the general problem :

$$a+b\leq 1$$

Under some constraint on $1>a,b>0$

Well a bit of algebra and trigonometric's formulae  shows that it's equivalent to :

$$\sin^2\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)+\sin^2\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\leq 1$$

But :

$$\sin^2\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)+\sin^2\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\leq \cos^2\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)+\sin^2\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$$

Or :
$$\sin^2\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\leq \cos^2\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\quad (1)$$

Or :

$$\Big(\sin\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\cos\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big(\sin\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)+\cos\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)\leq 0$$

The problem is :

$$\Big(\sin\Big(b\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\cos\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)$$

Or :

$$\Big(\cos\Big((b-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\cos\Big(a\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)$$

Now we use the fact :

$$\cos(p)-\cos(q)=-2\sin\Big(\frac{p+q}{2}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{p-q}{2}\Big)$$

We get :

$$-2\sin\Big(\frac{\pi(b+a-1)}{4}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{\pi(b-1-a)}{2}\Big)$$

Now it's clear that it's equivalent to the original problem.

Now the idea is using power series: factorize the expression. We have :

$$\cos^2(x)=\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{(2 i)^{-2 + n} (1 + (-1)^n) (-\frac{π}{2} + x)^n}{n!}$$
See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20cos%28x%29%5E2%20at%20x%3Dpi%2F2)

And :

$$\sin^2(x) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k 2^{-1 + 2 k} x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}$$

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20sin%28x%29%5E2%20at%20x%3D0)

Well now making the difference in the inequality $(1)$ we can factorize to get someting like :

$$0\leq \frac{\pi}{2}(a-1-b)\Big(P\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}a,\frac{\pi}{2}b\Big)\Big)$$

Here I have used the fact :

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(Q(x,y))$$

With $n\geq 1$ a natural number .

Now the problem is the :

$$P(\frac{\pi}{2}a,\frac{\pi}{2}b)\quad (2)$$

My questions :
Is it just unsuable ?
Can we have more informations on $(2)$ ,I mean as it is equal to zero ?
Can we improve the situation ?
Can we have a good estimation of $(2)$  ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you claiming that $a+b\le1$ is equivalent to $\sin^2(a)+\sin^2(b)\leq 1$?

Comment: @MartinR Well you're right to point out this because there is a mistake . Let me correct it . Thanks !

Comment: @MartinR Can you tell me if it's clean now ? If it's right don't feel compel to response . Have a good day and take care .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What do you think about all of this ? Thanks and good day cheers !